# Why is my throughput and average io rate got slower when i add node to my Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, io, mapreduce, benchmarking, throughput

So i run a TestDFSIO on my cluster to see the throughput and avg io rate of read and write operation. 
i do 4 test:
4 files 256 MB each (total 1 GB)
2 files 256 MB each (total 512 MB)
2 files 128 MB each (total 256 MB)
1 files 50 MB (total 50 MB)

and i run those on single-node to 5-node hadoop cluster. with 256 MB blocksize and for each node have different replication (single-node = 1 replication, 2 node = 2 replication and so on).

here's the test result of the 1 GB data test
1 node

```
----- TestDFSIO ----- : write
           Date & time: Thu Jun 20 11:38:21 WIB 2019
       Number of files: 4
Total MBytes processed: 1024.0
     Throughput mb/sec: 8.503288381053611
Average IO rate mb/sec: 8.507380485534668
 IO rate std deviation: 0.18595730311606032
    Test exec time sec: 84.876

----- TestDFSIO ----- : read
           Date & time: Thu Jun 20 11:39:52 WIB 2019
       Number of files: 4
Total MBytes processed: 1024.0
     Throughput mb/sec: 14.351786965662228
Average IO rate mb/sec: 14.422638893127441
 IO rate std deviation: 1.0515649052955383
    Test exec time sec: 61.371

2 node
----- TestDFSIO ----- : write
           Date & time: Thu Jun 20 11:15:52 WIB 2019
       Number of files: 4
Total MBytes processed: 1024.0
     Throughput mb/sec: 2.557167936510315
Average IO rate mb/sec: 2.5574562549591064
 IO rate std deviation: 0.027311795003682558
    Test exec time sec: 150.506

----- TestDFSIO ----- : read
           Date & time: Thu Jun 20 11:18:04 WIB 2019
       Number of files: 4
Total MBytes processed: 1024.0
     Throughput mb/sec: 9.567321617101587
Average IO rate mb/sec: 9.673456192016602
 IO rate std deviation: 1.0593562755825534
    Test exec time sec: 79.333

3 node
----- TestDFSIO ----- : write
           Date & time: Thu Jun 20 10:42:47 WIB 2019
       Number of files: 4
Total MBytes processed: 1024.0
     Throughput mb/sec: 2.343067129788529
Average IO rate mb/sec: 2.3866918087005615
 IO rate std deviation: 0.3233444726530288
    Test exec time sec: 167.593

----- TestDFSIO ----- : read
           Date & time: Thu Jun 20 10:47:33 WIB 2019
       Number of files: 4
Total MBytes processed: 1024.0
     Throughput mb/sec: 11.901164547546546
Average IO rate mb/sec: 12.255699157714844
 IO rate std deviation: 2.2415787547598667
    Test exec time sec: 69.29

4 node 
----- TestDFSIO ----- : write
           Date & time: Thu Jun 20 10:23:19 WIB 2019
       Number of files: 4
Total MBytes processed: 1024.0
     Throughput mb/sec: 1.6539390885245053
Average IO rate mb/sec: 1.6625666618347168
 IO rate std deviation: 0.12093049037575003
    Test exec time sec: 205.164

----- TestDFSIO ----- : read
           Date & time: Thu Jun 20 10:25:23 WIB 2019
       Number of files: 4
Total MBytes processed: 1024.0
     Throughput mb/sec: 19.842653954966476
Average IO rate mb/sec: 20.02923583984375
 IO rate std deviation: 1.9719328195872965
    Test exec time sec: 57.25

5 node
----- TestDFSIO ----- : write
           Date & time: Thu Jun 13 12:50:12 WIB 2019
       Number of files: 4
Total MBytes processed: 1024.0
     Throughput mb/sec: 1.5617159964556366
Average IO rate mb/sec: 1.573684573173523
 IO rate std deviation: 0.14426118715726127
    Test exec time sec: 219.959

----- TestDFSIO ----- : read
           Date & time: Thu Jun 13 14:01:01 WIB 2019
       Number of files: 4
Total MBytes processed: 1024.0
     Throughput mb/sec: 18.00692844707827
Average IO rate mb/sec: 18.323461532592773
 IO rate std deviation: 2.501963465819598
    Test exec time sec: 64.316
```

i thought with more nodes, the work got more parallelize and increase the throughput. why the write operation going down considerably when new node is added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data sizes are too small.  An single system can easily handle 1 GB of data.  Considering this is the largest size you're using it's not surprising you're seeing these results.

Raise this several orders of magnitude to something like 100GB-1TB otherwise it doesn't make any sense to derive performance results from this type of testing.

Comment: but what is the reason my single-node is faster than my 5 node cluster in the write/read test? i know that my data test is too small, but that is because my setup is 2GB memory, 220 GB space, and 2 cores each. 
i think it can't run a very big data that well.

Comment: @Andre: round-trip communication overhead might be the bottleneck for small tests.

Comment: @PeterCordes so, because the data is on different places and it is rather small, the communication overhead becoming bigger than the benefit of parallel computing?